# Vertical align of two divs within another div without using display:flex

Tags: html, css

I want to align to the top the content of two `divs` that are within another `div`.

I can't use `display: flexbox`, also it must be inline css. It's displaying how I want when the description `div` contains only one line, but when it contains multiple lines the `div` with the number displays above the description `div`
This is my code for now:

```html
<!--Single line-->
<div style="margin:10px 0 10px 0;">
  <div style="display:inline-block; vertical-align:top"> 1.1</div>
  <div style="margin-left:50px; display: inline-block; vertical-align:top;">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, pertinax honestatis suscipiantur mea eu, populo invidunt nam ne, nulla similique usu et. His accusata definitionem in.
  </div>
</div>

<!--Multiple lines-->
<div style="margin:10px 0 10px 0;">
  <div style="display:inline-block; vertical-align:top">1.2</div>
  <div style="margin-left:50px; display: inline-block; vertical-align:top;">
    Id harum paulo bonorum vim, sit adhuc aliquid oportere in, ei quo dicta labitur salutatus. Debet doctus facilis ius ad, assum expetendis vix ex. Modus nostro concludaturque nec ad. No unum appellantur sea, assum oratio legere has et, est lorem concludaturque
    id. Ex pro audire nostrud, vel sale dissentias an, eos no zril vocibus principes. Noluisse praesent mei ea. Eam intellegat omittantur ea, sit tacimates quaestio definitiones ei. Et vix appareat reprehendunt, at cum alii aliquando, audire iuvaret instructior
    has eu. Sea id placerat ponderum, ea has deserunt assentior consectetuer. Nobis denique nominavi qui ut, cu prima idque perfecto eos. Quo soleat possit impedit eu. Id mucius graeci noluisse his. Sanctus appareat usu ne, per ea purto tractatos deterruisset.
  </div>
</div>
```

I would like every item to be displayed like `1.1`:
[image]

Comment: @StackSlave for all we know, this is going in to an email where inline styles are totally acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if inline elements are in play, I'll assume tables are fair game too :P

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 3rem; vertical-align: top">1.1</td>
      <td>
        <p style="margin-top: 0;">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, pertinax honestatis suscipiantur mea eu, populo invidunt nam ne, nulla similique usu et. His accusata definitionem in.
        </p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 3rem; vertical-align: top">1.2</td>
      <td>
        <p style="margin-top: 0;">
          Id harum paulo bonorum vim, sit adhuc aliquid oportere in, ei quo dicta labitur salutatus. Debet doctus facilis ius ad, assum expetendis vix ex. Modus nostro concludaturque nec ad.

          No unum appellantur sea, assum oratio legere has et, est lorem concludaturque id. Ex pro audire nostrud, vel sale dissentias an, eos no zril vocibus principes. Noluisse praesent mei ea. Eam intellegat omittantur ea, sit tacimates quaestio definitiones ei. Et vix appareat reprehendunt, at cum alii aliquando, audire iuvaret instructior has eu. Sea id placerat ponderum, ea has deserunt assentior consectetuer.

          Nobis denique nominavi qui ut, cu prima idque perfecto eos. Quo soleat possit impedit eu. Id mucius graeci noluisse his. Sanctus appareat usu ne, per ea purto tractatos deterruisset.
        </p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

your problem is that you need to provide a `width` to your container.

```css
.number {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.text {
 display: inline-block;
 width: 80%;
}
```

```html
//Single line
       <div>
            <div class="number"> 1.1</div> <div class="text">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, pertinax honestatis suscipiantur mea eu, populo invidunt nam ne, nulla similique usu et. His accusata definitionem in.
    </div>
        </div>

//Multiple lines
<div>
    <div class="number">1.2</div> <div class="text">
    Id harum paulo bonorum vim, sit adhuc aliquid oportere in, ei quo dicta labitur salutatus. Debet doctus facilis ius ad, assum expetendis vix ex. Modus nostro concludaturque nec ad.

    No unum appellantur sea, assum oratio legere has et, est lorem concludaturque id. Ex pro audire nostrud, vel sale dissentias an, eos no zril vocibus principes. Noluisse praesent mei ea. Eam intellegat omittantur ea, sit tacimates quaestio definitiones ei. Et vix appareat reprehendunt, at cum alii aliquando, audire iuvaret instructior has eu. Sea id placerat ponderum, ea has deserunt assentior consectetuer.

    Nobis denique nominavi qui ut, cu prima idque perfecto eos. Quo soleat possit impedit eu. Id mucius graeci noluisse his. Sanctus appareat usu ne, per ea purto tractatos deterruisset.
</div>
</div>
```

with `flexbox` is the easiest way to perform it

```css
.container {
  display: flex;  
}

.space {
 margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
//Single line
       <div class="container">
            <div class="space">1.1</div>
            <div>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, pertinax honestatis suscipiantur mea eu, populo invidunt nam ne, nulla similique usu et. His accusata definitionem in.
            </div>
       </div>

//Multiple lines
<div class="container">
    <div class="space">1.2</div> <div>
    Id harum paulo bonorum vim, sit adhuc aliquid oportere in, ei quo dicta labitur salutatus. Debet doctus facilis ius ad, assum expetendis vix ex. Modus nostro concludaturque nec ad.

    No unum appellantur sea, assum oratio legere has et, est lorem concludaturque id. Ex pro audire nostrud, vel sale dissentias an, eos no zril vocibus principes. Noluisse praesent mei ea. Eam intellegat omittantur ea, sit tacimates quaestio definitiones ei. Et vix appareat reprehendunt, at cum alii aliquando, audire iuvaret instructior has eu. Sea id placerat ponderum, ea has deserunt assentior consectetuer.

    Nobis denique nominavi qui ut, cu prima idque perfecto eos. Quo soleat possit impedit eu. Id mucius graeci noluisse his. Sanctus appareat usu ne, per ea purto tractatos deterruisset.
</div>
</div>
```